# Redis & NodeJS - Connection exception

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using Redis DB with NodeJS. Occasionally I get below exception and my server (NodeJS) crashes only to restart again.

```
Error: Redis connection to localhost:6380 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Can someone explain why this happens? Does the below config has something to do with this?

```
# Set the max number of connected clients at the same time. By default
# this limit is set to 10000 clients, however if the Redis server is not
# able ot configure the process file limit to allow for the specified limit
# the max number of allowed clients is set to the current file limit
# minus 32 (as Redis reserves a few file descriptors for internal uses).
#
# Once the limit is reached Redis will close all the new connections sending
# an error 'max number of clients reached'.
#
# maxclients 10000
```

Comment: What you get for following command ? `./redis-cli -p 6380`, assumed that you are in redis/src directory.

Comment: I get the client console where I can run my redis commands.

Comment: Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your call to `redis.createClient()`.

Comment: Using 'localhost' also works for me, the problem is occasionally I get the connection exception. However, I'll replace 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1' and monitor logs to check if I get the same exception again. Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue (node "redis" module), while python "redis" module it works on the same redis instance. The Redis Cache is on MS Azure.

Comment: use **redis://localhost:6380** instead of `localhost:6380` in connection config

Answer (score 7):

This simply means your redis server isn't running; at least not on that address/port.

Start your server using

```
$ redis-server path/to/redis.conf
```

Also the default redis port is **6379**. If you're using 6380 in your scripts, make sure redis is listening on that port.

---

If something in your script is causing the redis server to crash, you can try listening for errors to get some more sensible output

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(6380, "localhost");

client.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Redis error encountered", err);
});

client.on("end", function() {
  console.log("Redis connection closed");
});
```

Comment: I have configured the redis instance to run on 6380 port. I want to know why / what makes the redis server stop.

Comment: Perhaps you're issuing a query that causes it to crash?

Comment: Also try handling "ready" state for redisClient. `client.on("ready",function(res){})`. What are you getting for above error and ready states,? print it on console.

Comment: Also check parameters to createClient() function, first is port and then it is server name.

Comment: Following the right format, `var redis = require('redis'),
client = redis.createClient(6380, 'localhost');`. Just FYI, am using node redis module listed [here](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). Also, I'm handling states (_error_, _ready_, _connect_).